# Rails: Changing Error Messages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, flash, message

My error messages are not showing automatically, so I decided to use *flash* as a workaround. This is what I'm doing

**Controller:**

```
flash[:notice] = @post.errors.full_messages
```

**View:**

```
<%= flash[:notice] %>
```

Then, I get this ugly error message on my view.

```
["Content can't be blank", "Content is too short (minimum is 10 characters)"]
```

But at least, the user successfully gets the error message. Now I need to customize the error message and make it look a little bit more pretty. I guess I could parse each error sentence into some local variables and show them (is there a more sophisticated way?). However, I don't know how to customize the error message. For example, "Content can't be blank" should be changed to "You left the content blank". Where can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

What happens is that when @post contains some validation errors doing `@post.errors.full_messages` returns an array of errors that happened during validation.

To display them nicely you might want to do something like

```
<%- flash[:notice].each do |error| %>
  <%= error %>
<% end %>
```

**EDIT**
Whoops I misread the question.

These errors are validation errors in your model where you have the validations like

`validates` you can pass custom messages like so

`validates :content, :presence => { :message => "You left the content blank" }`

**Update**: check this link out for the options you have

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods/validates